# Clear and reuse a Canvas, or create new object?

Tags: java, gwt, java-canvas

My setup:

I have a `GWT Canvas` that displays some grafics that rely on heavy algorithms. The objects are dragable, and therefore on drag I save everything beside the dragged object on a temporary canvas and reuse this as an image behind the dragging context.

My question:
My drag canvas is a reused Canvas object, that has first to be cleared before saving the static context to it before dragging starts.
I wonder if "reuse and clear" is better than "create a new canvas object".

What do you think?

Either clear canvas everytime:

```
private Canvas canvas;
void buffer() {
   canvas.getContext2d().clearRect(0, 0, Window.getClientWidth(), Window.getClientHeight());
   //...draw
}
```

...or create new object:

```
void buffer() {
   Canvas canvas = Canvas.createIfSupported();
   //draw
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Reuse and clear" is superior. It is more efficient since it only calls the native `clearRect(x, y, w, h)`. There are many events that fire during the addition and removal widgets. I would use a new object only if it were a logical concept. You may also want to consider [Lienzo](http://emitrom.com/lienzo).